# dscverify: nanomsg_0.4~beta+dfsg-3.dsc failed signature check

Tags: debian, backports

I'm trying to backport `libnanomsg-dev` from `jessie` to `squeeze`. And `dget` says:

```
$ dget -x http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nanomsg/nanomsg_0.4~beta+dfsg-3.dsc
dget: retrieving http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nanomsg/nanomsg_0.4~beta+dfsg-3.dsc
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2016  100  2016    0     0  47558      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 96000
dget: using existing nanomsg_0.4~beta+dfsg.orig.tar.gz
dget: using existing nanomsg_0.4~beta+dfsg-3.debian.tar.xz
nanomsg_0.4~beta+dfsg-3.dsc:
dscverify: nanomsg_0.4~beta+dfsg-3.dsc failed signature check:
gpg: Signature made Fri 29 Aug 2014 09:49:58 PM EEST using RSA key ID 864CC8BF
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
Validation FAILED!!
```

As far as I can tell, I've got to install `jessie`'s keyring somehow. But how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyring is stored in the `debian-keyring` package, so to install the Jessie keyring you can do

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debian-keyring/debian-keyring_2014.12.10_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i debian-keyring_2014.12.10_all.deb
```

This is safe, because `debian-keyring` doesn’t contain *archive* keys (which are used to verify downloaded binary packages), but maintainer keys (which are used to verify source packages). The only potential inconvenience resulting from installing a new `debian-keyring` package is that `dget` will complain when unpacking older packages signed by keys which are no longer in `debian-keyring`. See [`man dscverify`](https://manpages.debian.org/dscverify) for details.

Alternatively, to continue your backport without upgrading your keyring, you can simply extract the files `dget` downloaded for you without verifying the signature:

```
dpkg-source -x nanomsg_0.4~beta+dfsg-3.dsc
```

You can skip the verification entirely by using `dget`’s `-u` option:

```
dget -u http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nanomsg/nanomsg_0.4~beta+dfsg-3.dsc
```

(`-x` is the default and doesn’t need to be specified).